# What flash power would I need from 2 units, when shooting at f13 and 1/200s ISO100?

Tags: flash, exposure

Could someone be so kind as to help me figure out the flash strength I would need for this?

Settings:
D3200, Sigma 70mm Macro.
YN560 III & YN560 IV, triggered by the 560-TX.
F13, 1/200s and ISO100.

I am guessing 1/32 on both units.

I welcome links where I can educate myself on this and figure it out myself. Believe me, I've tried, but none give me what I want, most are extremely dumbed down explanations of exposure as a concept and not the 3 components of it.

Answer (score 2):

Light from a flash (or any point source lamp) falls off rapidly with distance. If we double the distance between subject and flash, the light playing on the subject decreases to ¼ its original value. Thus nobody can answer your question without knowing the distances involve and whether one or two flashes are to be used. If two, what distances etc.

Guide number to the rescue (maybe).

Both  units sport a guide number of 190 for ISO 100. How can I set my camera using the guide number? We divide the flash to subject distance by the guide number to calculate the aperture setting. As an example, suppose the flash unit is near the camera and the subject distance is 6 feet. The math is 190 ÷ 6 = 32 (rounded). Thus 32 is the f/number setting to use.

You need to know that guide numbers are based on average indoor room conditions. The idea is to take into account that quantity of flash energy that is reflected from ceiling and wall etc.

Should you choose to go the guide number route, you can improve the accuracy by determining the actual guide number for your setup. Measure the flash to subject distance, say it’s 10 feet. Set you camera on 100 ISO. Set the shutter on the fastest speed that synchronizes (consult camera manual for this speed).  Make an exposure sequence thus f/4 –  f/5.6 –  f/11 –  f/22 –  f/32. Examine the images, choose the best. Say it is the one shot at f/11.  Now multiply f/number times distance = f/11 X 10 feet = 11 X 10 = 110. This method calculates a guide number for your setup.

Using the published guide number of 190 and a flash to subject distance of 16 feet, the aperture setting will be: 190 ÷ 16 =  f/11. If you choose to shoot at f/8, this aperture allows 2X more light into the camera, you compensate by setting the flash at ½ power. To use f/5.6, set the power at ¼ because f/5.6 allows twice again more light to transverse the lens.

If you aim two identical units at the subject, both equal distance, the amount of light playing on the subject doubles. The revised guide number is the single flash guide number multiplied by 1.4. Thus if you aim both the 560III and the 560IV and both are equidistant, the guide number is  190 X 1.4 = 266.

Note: Guide numbers work however, you should test and calculate for your specific setup.

Answer (score 2):

> Settings: D3200, Sigma 70mm Macro. YN560 III & YN560 IV, triggered by the 560-TX. F13, 1/200s and ISO100.
>
> I am guessing 1/32 on both units.

**It depends** on what/how you're shooting. But I think you're being wildly optimistic on how much light your $70 flashes can put out if you're shooting portraits. Although, if you were going for a black background, I think you'll get that for sure. BTW, there aren't three components of exposure with flash. There are five.

- Ambient exposure is controlled by iso, aperture, and shutter speed.
- Flash exposure is controlled by iso, aperture, flash power, and flash-to-subject distance.

And you can balance the two any way you please.  Asking are these settings good, is a lot like asking "If I use iso x, aperture y, and shutter speed z, will I get a good exposure?" about ambient exposure--the answer is, **it depends**.

**The easiest way for you to figure it out is to just do it and chimp** (look at the image/histogram on the back of the camera).  You'll learn soon enough that way.  But I can tell you from my experience, unless you're doing a macro shoot or just using the flashes for a tiny bit of fill, and even then it might not work, you'll probably be underexposed at those settings.

I usually start with my camera set to 1/200s (camera's sync speed), iso 400, f/4, and 1/8 power on the flashes and adjust from there. To me, that's the happy medium.  But I'm also using a 580EXII, which has about one stop over a YN-560.  You might want to start around 1/4 power.

Note, how your settings would be roughly -7.3EV (-2EV on iso, -3.3EV on aperture, and -2EV on flash power) from my starting point. Or ~1/160th (2<sup>7.3</sup>) of the same amount of light. Even with your flash on full power, you wouldn't get the same amount of light, if you left everything else the same (1/64→full power is only six stops).

Speedlights are still just running off AA batteries. They are the *lowest*-powered lights in the world of strobes.  It's all about conserving the flash energy.  You're making your flashes work awfully hard by using f/13 or iso 100.

One site you might want to look at to figure some of this stuff out is Neil van Niekerk's Tangents site, starting with the [Flash Photography Techniques](http://neilvn.com/tangents/flash-photography-techniques/flash-photography-basics/) section.  You can also go to David Hobby's [Strobist](http://www.strobist.com) website, but it's often easiest to start with a single TTL flash, and begin with on-camera bouncing; just as it's easiest for some folks to start with their camera in automated modes, like P or A/Av before going to M.

Answer (score 1):

Flash exposure is different than the "three components of continuous ambient'.  Flash exposure is Not affected by shutter speed, but a more huge difference, flash exposure is greatly affected by the distance between flash and subject (flash and local lights fall off fast with distance, but sunlight does not, not here on Earth).

The Yongnuo 560 III manual has guide number table, showing 35mm zoom is for example Guide Number 128 feet, or 39 meters.

This means, if at 35 mm zoom, then full power at f/13 should reach 128/13 = 9.8 feet, or 39/13 = 3 meters.

See http://www.scantips.com/lights/flashbasics1c.html about Guide Number.